# interface out classes in javascript to de-couple

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I'm trying to understand the first part of this [tutorial](https://jamesmonger.com/post/react-component-dependency-injection.htm) the interface part, not the IOC part.
I think the wording is pretty confusing so just wanted to get a more clear explanation.

This quote in the tutorial is what I'm not understanding.

> Therefore, so that our code isn’t as tightly coupled, we should
> interface out the dependencies and reference these interfaces instead.

I created an example fiddle exactly like the tutorial above does using interfaces.
https://jsfiddle.net/89w32ajh/13/

What decoupling am I getting from the first class example to the interface one? Apart from interfaces making it more contract like where you must have what the interface requires in the class itself.

I just don't see the decoupling that he talks about in his quote.
I'm still calling a new Plant() and a new WateringCan() in the constructor.

```
interface IPlant {
    name: string;
}

class Plant implements IPlant {
  public name: string;
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

interface IWateringCan {
    material: string;
    water (plant: IPlant): void;
}

class WateringCan implements IWateringCan {
  private material: string;
  constructor(material: string){
    this.material = material;
  }
  
  public water(plant: Plant) {
    const str = plant.name + 'is been watered by a ' + this.material + ' waterign can';
    return str;
  }
}

class Gardener {
    private plant: IPlant;
    private wateringCan: IWateringCan;

    constructor () {
     this.plant = new Plant("Daffodil");
     this.wateringCan = new WateringCan("Steel");
    }

    public waterPlant(): void {
        return this.wateringCan.water(this.plant);
    }
};

const gardner = new Gardener();
gardner.waterPlant();
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later, when you refactor the code and provide a different implementation, or when you inject an implementation, the contract remains the same, and your type checker will tell you if the new implementation satisfies it.

Without this, when you put the concrete implementation as the type, as soon as you change the implementation you will change the type at the same time, and you have no guarantee that the new implementation satisfies the contract.

Also, when you build the new implementation, you can implement the contract, and you get things like "Implement all required members" and errors until you satisfy the contract.

With only a single concrete implementation, the only benefit is during a replacement of that component (future refactoring). If you move to injectable components - like optional database connectors, then you get the benefit of contract-based interfaces.

Later you can create a `BigPlant` class that implements `IPlant`, and with a small refactor support injected dependencies. It is as simple as:

```
class Gardener {
    private plant: IPlant;
    private wateringCan: IWateringCan;

    constructor (PlantClass: IPlant) {
     this.plant = new PlantClass("Daffodil");
     this.wateringCan = new WateringCan("Steel");
    }

    public waterPlant(): void {
        return this.wateringCan.water(this.plant);
    }
};
```

In practice, you can use this for things like injecting a database provider where you don't know or care about the underlying database - just that the db provider implements the contract that you need.

That way your application can support various DBs, rather than being tightly coupled to a specific database provider.

Comment: With only a single concrete implementation, the only benefit is during a replacement of that component. Which component are you referring to ?

Comment: Anything that is specified as a dependency using an interface rather than the concrete type. In this case, plant and wateringCan. You can make a BigPlant type that implements IPlant, and you make one change in the code: this.plant = new BigPlant("Daffodil");

The next step is injecting the dependencies.

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying. So basically it's what I thought you only get the contract and not exactly decoupling.

Comment: Without an interface, you would have to change the type of the plant property, and you couldn't inject another type in the constructor. You would have to extend the type signature of the constructor with a union type for each concrete type that it could take.

Comment: The contract creates decoupling, you are just not using it yet.

Comment: You lost me again. "and you couldn't inject another type in the constructor " What constructor and where is injection even happening here ?

Comment: The next step is to take the implementation as a constructor parameter. So you take a class that satisfies IPlant as a constructor parameter, and instantiate that. So now you can pass in Plant or BigPlant, with no change to the code of this class.

Comment: That's a very small code change, with total type safety, to support various concrete dependencies. Because you already decoupled the implementation using interfaces. So the refactor is very light, and safe.

Comment: Would you mind showing me an example of what you are referring to as constructor parameter in my example ?

Comment: I added it to the answer.

Comment: Ok I see, so you would instantiate it like new Gardener(Plant); So if you had a BigPlant with the same IPlant contract. You could pass that in new Gardener(BigPlant); and it wouldn't break like the concrete setup ?